# Have a batch file check the value of a registry key, echo if it is set how I want and change it if it is not

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file

I want to have a script that will check the following Registry Key for

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceGuard\Scenarios\HypervisorEnforcedCodeIntegrity
Enabled Reg_DWORD 0x0
```

If the value is set to 0x0, I want the script to echo `Hypervisor Enforced Code Integrity is Disabled`

If the value is set to anything else, I want to script to echo a statement, and then edit the registry value.

This is what I have so far, my issue is that the for /f command keeps erroring out. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
Set regkey="HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceGuard\Scenarios\HypervisorEnforcedCodeIntegrity"
Set Value=Enabled

for /f "tokens=2* delims=    "
%%A IN (reg query %regkey% /v %Value%) DO SET base=%%B
if %base%=0x0 && goto Disabled else goto Enabled

:Disabled
echo Hypervisor Enforced Code Integrity is Disabled
pause
exit

:Enabled
echo Hypervisor Enforced Code Integrity is Enabled
echo
echo Continuing will Disable Hypervisor Enforced Code Integrity and then your computer will reboot
echo 
echo ****Save your work before continuting****
pause
reg add %regkey% /v %value% /t REG_DWORD /d 0x0

shutdown /r /f /t 005 /c "Restarting to Disable Hypervisor Enforced Code Integrity"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue, is a failure to read or understand the basic command usage information. If you open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?`, and press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, you should see that you are using:

```bash
FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN (file-set) DO command [command-parameters]
```

Instead of:

```bash
FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ('command') DO command [command-parameters]
```

However, there are several things you could do to improve your script, for this, and future tasks, so I have included a rewritten example for you too. It includes sections which are reusable for other registry checks, a user modifiable registry key and value pair to use with those, and parts specific only to the task laid out in the question.

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Rem The next two lines are user editable.
Set "RegKey=HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceGuard\Scenarios\HypervisorEnforcedCodeIntegrity"
Set "RegVal=Enabled"

Rem please do not modify the next twenty three lines.
Set "Elv=0"
For %%G In (RegKey RegVal) Do If Not Defined %%G (
    %%G has not been defined.
    Set "Elv="
)
If Not Defined Elv GoTo EndIt

Set "RegData="
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In (
    '%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "%RegKey%" /V "%RegVal%" 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /RIC:"\<%RegVal%\>"'
) Do (
    Set "RegData=%%G"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    For /F "Tokens=1,*" %%H In ("!RegData:*%RegVal%=!") Do (
        EndLocal
        Set "RegData=%%I"
    )
)
If Not Defined RegData (
    Echo The registry information does not exist.
    GoTo EndIt
)

Rem The following five lines are specific to your task.
Set "Enabled=Disabled"
For %%G In (1 0x1 0x00000001) Do If "%RegData%" == "%%G" Set "Enabled=Enabled"
Echo Hypervisor Enforced Code Integrity is %Enabled%

If "%Enabled%" == "Disabled" GoTo EndIt

Rem Please do not modify the next seven lines.
Set "RegRoot=%RegKey:\="&:"%"
(Set RegRoot) 2>NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /XLI "HKLM HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" 1>NUL && Set "Elv=1" 

%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query HKU\S-1-5-19 1>NUL 2>&1 || (
    Echo To modify the registry, this script must be run elevated.
    GoTo EndIt
)

Rem The following nine lines are specific to your task.
Echo(
Echo Your computer needs to reboot to disable Hypervisor Enforced Code Integrity.
Echo(
Echo ****Please save your work before continuting.****
Pause

%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Add "%RegKey%" /V "%RegVal%" /T REG_DWORD /D 0 /F 1>NUL

%SystemRoot%\System32\shutdown.exe /R /T 5 /C "Restarting to Disable Hypervisor Enforced Code Integrity." /D P:2:4

Rem Please do not modify anything below.

:EndIt
Echo Press any key to exit . . .
Pause 1>NUL
Exit /B
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly! I'm still working on and trying to improve using for /f statements, reading through your code has clarified some things for me.